# Conditionally specify props of a component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I would like to include the showTimeSelect property in the ReactDatePicker component below if the {type} === 'dateTime', otherwise I want to omit it, but it's not currently working. I'm a React noob, so would appreciate guidance on getting this to work.

The purpose of this is because I'm using [ReactDatePicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-select-time) in a form and sometimes I would like it to display as a date picker and at other times I want it to show as a time picker. The way to do this is by adding in one property to the ReactDatePicker component, namely showTimeSelect.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
function FormDate({ name, question, register, control, type }) {

  const varShowTimeSelect = ({ type }) =>
    ({ type } === 'dateTime' ? { showTimeSelect } : {});

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{question}</label>
      <div className="input-group date col-xs-5">
        <Controller
          as={
            <ReactDatePicker
              dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
              placeholderText="Select date"
              {varShowTimeSelect} //Conditionally show showTimeSelect prop
            />
          }
          control={control}
          name={name}
          ref={register}
          id={name}
          valueName="selected"
          onChange={([selected]) => selected}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default FormDate;
```

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the condition within the property value as `showTimeSelect` accepts a `boolean` type:

```
<ReactDatePicker
  dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
  placeholderText="Select date"
  showTimeSelect={type === 'dateTime'}
/>
```

---

```
function FormDate({ name, question, register, control, type }) {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{question}</label>
      <div className="input-group date col-xs-5">
        <Controller
          as={
            <ReactDatePicker
              dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
              placeholderText="Select date"
              showTimeSelect={type === 'dateTime'}
            />
          }
          control={control}
          name={name}
          ref={register}
          id={name}
          valueName="selected"
          onChange={([selected]) => selected}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Dennis for your help - I love the simplicity of this, but for some reason it doesn't change the datepicker type? If I hard code showTimeSelect into the ReactDatePicker component, it makes all the date pickers into time pickers. But if I instead use the line showTimeSelect={type === 'dateTime'} then it just keeps them as date pickers even though type is dateTime. Can you think why that might be? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually, it was my bad!! I was calling the wrong component so the type was never dateTime! I have fixed that error and your solution works perfectly! I love how simple it is. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Dennis suggested (which I think is the better solution in this case), if you want to conditionally not pass the prop *at all*, you'd want to do use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
function FormDate({ name, question, register, control, type }) {

  const showTimeSelectProps = type === 'dateTime' ? { showTimeSelect: true } : {};

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{question}</label>
      <div className="input-group date col-xs-5">
        <Controller
          as={
            <ReactDatePicker
              dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
              placeholderText="Select date"
              {...showTimeSelectProps} //Conditionally show showTimeSelect prop
            />
          }
          control={control}
          name={name}
          ref={register}
          id={name}
          valueName="selected"
          onChange={([selected]) => selected}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks cbr - I tried out both your solution and Dennis's and both work perfectly! Thanks so much. I have ticked Dennis's answer as the correct one mainly because you said it was the better answer - lol! But both work and this approach will probably come in useful at some point. Thanks again :-)

Comment: By the way, I've already found a reason to use this approach in a different place :-) I'm using it to conditionally write a different placeholderText depending on whether it's a date or dateTime. Awesome :-) Thanks cbr

Comment: Great! This one is useful if there are multiple props that need to be switched between. If there's only one, remember that whatever goes inside the curly braces in the prop's value (`prop={/*here*/}`) can contain any javascript expression, so you can also use ternaries: `placeholderText={isFoo ? 'Foo' : 'Bar'}`

Comment: Fantastic! Loving that! Thank you :D